# Simple ARRAYFORMULA issue

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to get a simple IF statement into my ARRAYFORMULA but I'm getting a formula parse error. I'm unsure why.

Here's what I've got. Any ideas what I'm missing?

```
=ArrayFormula({"Column Name";if(ISBLANK(C2:C),"",if(and(E2:E="b",G2:G">1.9"),G2:G-0.5,"")}))
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kh_gNxouYN7nL3xAnqsG8GvNGDxji5DkD6zZs0nSgxg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hm, that's not working. I tried that change and included a sample sheet in the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had your parentheses mismatched. First, select all of Col J and press "Delete" to make sure it is completely empty. Then place this in J1:

`=ArrayFormula({"Stop@2";if(ISBLANK(C2:C),"",if((E2:E="b")*(G2:G>1.9),G2:G-0.5,""))})`

To be more specific about your error, you had `=ArrayFormula({ ... }))`; so your outer `IF` had no closure while your `ArrayFormula` wrap had two.

Comment: Ah, thanks for catching that. It's working great now. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Even the best of us can at times miss things that drive us crazy.